# Why can't I run this script?

Tags: bash, quoting

```
$ sh bashtrrrrrr 

# whats my pub. ip?
bashtrrrrrr: line 19: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bashtrrrrrr: line 20: szintaktikai hiba:  váratlan fájl vég


$  cat bashtrrrrrr 
#!/bin/bash

echo '
# what's my pub. ip?
alias myip="curl -s "http://checkip.dyndns.org/" | grep -o "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" | head -1"

# shorten ssh connection with tsocks
function t() { read THEIP; tsocks ssh root@$THEIP; }

# red/green terminals regarding exit code
export PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="`
if [[ \$? = "0" ]];
then echo "\\[\\033[0;32m\\]";
else echo "\\[\\033[0;31m\\]";
fi`[\u@\h \w]\[\e[m\] "'

export PS1

' >> /home/USER/.bashrc
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also putting the whole `echo '...'` command into

```
cat  <<'EOF' >> /home/USER/.bashrc

...

EOF
```

would help you to get rid the many of the internal quotes.

Answer (score 11):

As the other answers mention, the issue is nested quotes.

I suggest you review [how quoting works in bash](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting).  In short, quotes
(of any kind, single quotes `'`, double quotes `"` or backticks `)
are *almost* always matched with the first occurrence of a quote of the
same kind; you have to *escape* a quote in order for it not to match
(but you cannot escape single quotes `'`).

So, (1) the apostrophe in `what's` closes the single quote in `echo '`:

```
echo '
# what's my pub. ip?
```

In other words, your `echo` command ends after `... ip?` and the rest
is immediately executed by bash as a command, which is apparently not
what you meant.

As [Rajish' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/why-cant-i-run-this-script/14984#14984) suggests, using [here-documents](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) solves many of the quoting
issues:

```
echo >> /home/USER/.bashrc <<'__EOF__'
# what's my pub ip?
echo "we can nest quotes in here"
__EOF__
```

(2) Then, as already reported in [ultrasawblade's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/why-cant-i-run-this-script/14982#14982), the quotes on this line do
not match properly:

```
alias myip="curl -s "http://checkip.dyndns.org/" | grep -o "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" | head -1"
```

You likely the want the first and the last `"` (double quote)
characters on the line to match, but bash matches them in the order
they are encountered on the line (left-to-right), so the double quote
left of `"http://...` closes the quotes after `alias myip="`.
Similarly, `| grep -o` and `| head -1` are considered *within*
quotes, and `http://...` and `[0-9]*\....` are *not*.  (This won't
have any serious syntactical consequences in this case, apart from
`grep` not seeing the backslashes, but keep it in mind for the
future.)

One solution is to escape the double quotes (and also the backslashes,
as backslashes do not lose their special meaning inside double quotes):

```
alias myip="curl -s \"http://checkip.dyndns.org/\" | grep -o \"[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*\" | head -1"
```

Another workaround, which works in this case, is to use single quotes
`'` instead; either for defining the alias:

```
alias myip='curl -s "http://checkip.dyndns.org/" | grep -o "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" | head -1'
```

or for the commands in the alias definition:

```
alias myip="curl -s 'http://checkip.dyndns.org/' | grep -o '[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*' | head -1"
```

(3) Finally, at lines:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="`
if [[ \$? = "0" ]];
```

The `'` (single quote) character after `PROMPT_COMMAND=` is
interpreted as starting a new multi-line singly-quoted string, 
which ends at line:

```
fi`[\u@\h \w]\[\e[m\] "'
```

Thus, another singly quoted string is started by the `'` character on
the last line, but bash never sees a matching single quote. Thus you
get the error:

```
unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, one problem is this line:

```
myip="curl -s "http://checkip.dyndns.org/" | grep -o "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" | head -1"
```

`bash` is confused by the quotes in the middle of the string.  When you put "quotes within quotes", you usually want to escape them, like so:

```
myip="curl -s \"http://checkip.dyndns.org/\" | grep -o \"[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\" | head -1"
```